# Assistance with GLMM in either R or SPSS

Tags: r, data-analysis, spss

I am trying to figure out how to analyze my data. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The dataset includes 72 participants who answered a question with a dichotomous response (yes/no). There are two between-subject variables (age: 2 conditions - young/old, and Variable X: conditions- Up/Down,) and a within subject variable (Variable Y: 3 conditions, A, B, and C). An example of the dataset is attached as an image.

Example Data frame code for R

```
Participant <- c('A','B','C')
Age <- c('Young', 'Young', 'Old')
VariableX <- c('Up', 'Up', 'Down')
ConditionA <- c('Yes', 'No', 'Yes')
ConditionB <- c('No', 'Yes', 'No')
ConditionC <- c('Yes', 'Yes', 'No')
ExampleData <- dataframe(Participant, Age, VariableX, ConditionA, ConditionB, ConditionC)
```

I am trying to figure out what to run in order to see if there is an interaction effect between age, Variable X and Variable Y on the binomial response of participants.

I tried to run a GLMM (ominbus generalized mixed model with a binary logistic regression function) with the binary response (yes/no) across condition with pre-defined contrasts (Condition A-ConditionC, ConditionB-ConditionC) as a within-subjects variables, and age (Young, old) and condition Y (Up, Down) as between subject variables in SPSS. I am not sure however if we did it correctly. I received no output data for the significance value.

Any guidance on how to analyze and interpret the output would be greatly appreciated! **I am happy to analyze these data either in SPSS or in R.**

Comment: for interaction between two categorical variables, you can use `chisq.test` https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/chisq.test

Comment: Hi @SThomas, welcome to SO. Thanks for providing the data, so is this a statistics question? As in, you know how to use glmm in R (e.g user lme4) just that you don't know what is the correct model for your data

Comment: If this is the case, I suggest you post this on https://stats.stackexchange.com/. I can also vote to migrate it if you verify this is the case

Comment: Hello @StupidWolf, thanks for the welcome! So I would say it is both, I need help with using lme4 in R correctly, but I also need help interpreting it. Thank you much for the suggestions, I will post to the forum you provided!